# Website does not work when moving the files to another server?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

![enter image description here][1]I'm trying to troubleshoot this problem. I created a basic asp page with **Javascript** in one server which works fine at the moment but when I move the **asp page** and all the related files to the new server it does not work. What my asp page does is ask for last or first name in text box and it has button which after it is press it returns all the matches with contact info. from **Microsoft Access database**.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<!-- JQuery Library used so that phone_dir.js can use JQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Corporate Phone Directory</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#003399">
     <br>
     <br>
     <div style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial; color:#D6D6D6;"> 
      <table width="745" height="81" border="0" align="left" bordercolor="#003399">
      <tr>
    <td width="300" height="50" align="left" valign="top">
    <div align="left" valign="bottom">
    Search by either First or Last Name: 
    <br>
    <br>   
          <input name="Search" type="text" id="Search" value="">
          <input name="btnFind2" type="button" id="btnFind2" value="Find"   onClick="searchphonedirectory()">

    </div>
       </table>
      </div>
      <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
        <hr>
        <div style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial; color:#D6D6D6;"  align="left"   id='results'>
       <!-- Your results will go here -->
       </div>


     </body>
     </html>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function()
     {

    $( "#Search" ).keypress(function() 
       {
        if(event.keyCode==13) 
        {
            $("#btnFind2").click();
        }; // End of If key code = Enter function
    }); 

 });

 function searchphonedirectory()
 {  
    var searchentry = document.getElementById('search').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp2.readyState==4)
       {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =   xmlhttp2.responseText;
       }

     }
     xmlhttp2.open("GET","phoneResults.asp?searchentry="+searchentry,true);
     xmlhttp2.send();

 };
```

Other Code which generates the results.

```
 <!--#include file="ASPFiles/phoneDirectory.asp" -->
      <%

          response.expires=-1

      err.clear

     on error resume next
 '*----------------------------------------------------------------
   searchentry = request.querystring("searchentry")
 '*----------------------------------------------------------------


     sql = "SELECT PhoneDirectory.Name, PhoneDirectory.[Phone#], PhoneDirectory.OfficeExtension, 
     PhoneDirectory.[Mobile#] "
     sql = sql +"FROM PhoneDirectory "
     sql = sql +"WHERE (PhoneDirectory.LastName Like '" & searchentry & "%' OR     
     PhoneDirectory.FirstName Like '" & searchentry & "%' ) "
     sql =  sql + "ORDER BY LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME"

     set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
     rs.Open sql,conn

      'response.write(sql)
       response.write("<table>")
       response.write("<td width='22%' align='left' height='29'>Name</th>")
       response.write("<td width='11%' align='left' >Phone</th>")
       response.write("<td width='1%' align='left' >Ext</th>")
       response.write("<td width='12%' align='left' >Mobile</th>")
       response.write("</tr>")




  do until rs.EOF   



response.write("<tr>")

for each x in rs.Fields

    response.write("<td align='left' >" & x.value & "</td>")

next

rs.MoveNext

response.write("</tr>")

      loop

       response.write("</table>")
     %>
```

This one opens the database:

```
    <%
' FileName="Connection_odbc_conn_dsn.htm"
' Type="ADO" 
' DesigntimeType="ADO"
' HTTP="true"
' Catalog=""
' Schema=""
'Dim MM_phoneDirectory_STRING
'MM_phoneDirectory_STRING = "dsn=PhoneDB;"


 set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

'TESTING DB
 conn.Open(Server.Mappath("/webs/corporatenet2/databases/Phone_Directory.mdb"))


  %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is your error?

Comment: The button doesn't work. I get no results

Comment: Are you sure your application can reach the Database from the second server?  Can you point out which line is suppose to be used to get the data from the database?

Comment: Modern browsers have a "developer tools" panel. I suggest using that to see what is actually getting returned by the ajax call.

Comment: **Side Note:** Do yourself a favor and learn from the formatting I added to your question. All that `//This is the end of blah blah blah` crap can be avoided by formatting your code. As Rodrick said [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) or [firebug for firefox](http://getfirebug.com) will help you diagnose the problem. If you can't find the problem after that just update the question with what you find out.

Comment: the relevant information here would probably be the file phoneResults.asp, else we don't really know what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Apparently my edit was not saved because you added to your answer. I will not edit it again. Just look up how to format your code properly. There is really little need to comment code anymore. I wish I could direct you to a post about the reason why.

Comment: I see you are using `Microsoft Access database`. Make sure all the drivers and database files are relocated when you moved the server files.

Comment: I added more code. Im not if it helps

Comment: I don't think it the asp file is problem. It has to do with database im trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you missed to mention the event" in keypress event and remove the searchphonedirectory() function from HTML input "onClick",

```
 <input name="btnFind2" type="button" id="btnFind2" value="Find">
```

Add it to your javascript code like this.

```
 $( "#Search" ).keypress(function(event) 
 {
    if(event.keyCode==13) 
    {
       searchphonedirectory();
    }; // End of If key code = Enter function
}); //End of Search Keypress Function
```

hope it helps.

Comment: that does the same thing as the code currently now. whats your point?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer, but it will certainly help you in the right direction, if the problem is ASP based.

On the root of your web server *(\inetpub\wwwroot)*, create a folder called **errors**.  In that folder create a file called **error.asp** and paste the following into it...

```vb
<%Option Explicit%>
<%
    dim LOGON_USER
    LOGON_USER = UCASE(Request.ServerVariables ("LOGON_USER"))
    PATH = request.ServerVariables("PATH_TRANSLATED")
    Const lngMaxFormBytes = 2000
    Dim objASPError, blnErrorWritten, strServername, strServerIP, strRemoteIP
    Dim strMethod, lngPos, datNow, strQueryString, strURL,PATH
    Dim arrError,i
    If  Response.Buffer Then
        Response.Clear
        Response.Status = "500 Internal Server Error"
        Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        Response.Expires = 0
    End If

    Set objASPError = Server.GetLastError

%>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">

<html>

    <head>

        <title>eDischarge encountered an error...</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text-html; charset=Windows-1252">
        <link href="includes\stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
                html {
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }
                html body {
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }
                body {
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    color: #330000;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                p {
                    font-size: 90%;
                }
                .errortitle {
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    color: white;
                    font-size: 150%;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    width: 100%;
                    background-color: #770000;
                    padding: 1em;
                }
                .errorbody {
                    padding: 2em;
                    background: url(http://stas35/errors/images/error.gif) no-repeat top left;
                }
                .errormessage {
                    border-left: 10px solid #770000;
                    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
                    margin-left: 2em;
                    color: #770000;
                }
                .errorpadleft {
                    padding-left: 2em;
                }
            -->
        </style>

    </head>

    <%
        strError = strError & "<p><strong>Error Type:</strong></p>"
        strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & Server.HTMLEncode(objASPError.Category) & "</p>"
        If objASPError.ASPCode > "" Then 
            strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & Server.HTMLEncode(", " & objASPError.ASPCode) & "</p>"
        end if

        strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & Server.HTMLEncode(" (0x" & Hex(objASPError.Number) & ")" )  & "</p>"
        If objASPError.ASPDescription > "" Then 
            strError = strError & Server.HTMLEncode(objASPError.ASPDescription) & "<br/>"
        elseIF (objASPError.Description > "") Then 
            strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" &  Server.HTMLEncode(objASPError.Description)  & "</p>"
        end if

        blnErrorWritten = False

          ' Only show the Source if it is available and the request is from the same machine as IIS
        If objASPError.Source > "" Then
            strServername = LCase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"))
            strServerIP   = Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")
            strRemoteIP   = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
            If (strServername = "localhost" Or strServerIP = strRemoteIP) And objASPError.File <> "?" Then
                strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & Server.HTMLEncode(objASPError.File)
                If objASPError.Line > 0 Then 
                    strError = strError & ", line " & objASPError.Line
                end if
                If objASPError.Column > 0 Then 
                    strError = strError & ", column " & objASPError.Column
                end if
                strError = strError & "</p>"
                strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & Server.HTMLEncode(objASPError.Source) & "</p>"
                If objASPError.Column > 0 Then  strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & String((objASPError.Column - 1), "-") & "</p>"
                blnErrorWritten = True
            End If
        End If

        If Not blnErrorWritten And objASPError.File <> "?" Then
            strError =strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & Server.HTMLEncode(  objASPError.File)
            If objASPError.Line > 0 Then 
                strError =strError & Server.HTMLEncode(", line " & objASPError.Line)
            end if
            If objASPError.Column > 0 Then
                strError =strError & ", column " & objASPError.Column
            end if
            strError = strError & "</p>"
          End If

        strError = strError & "<p><strong>Browser Type:</strong></p>"
        strError = strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">" & Server.HTMLEncode(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")) & "</p>"

        strMethod = Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")
        If strMethod = "POST" Then
            strError =strError & "<p class=""errorpadleft"">POST Data: (" & Request.TotalBytes & " bytes "
            If lngPos > 1 Then strError =strError & "?" & Server.HTMLEncode(Left(Request.QueryString, (lngPos - 1)))
            strError =strError & ")</p>"
            arrError = split(Request.Form,"&")
            For i = LBound(arrError) To UBound(arrError)
                strError =strError & "<p>"  & Server.HTMLEncode(arrError(i)) & "</p>"
            Next
        End If

        strError = strError & _
            "<p>" & _
                "<strong>User Logon: </strong>" & LOGON_USER & "<br/>" & _
                "<strong>User IP: </strong>" & Request.ServerVariables ("REMOTE_ADDR") & "<strong><br/>" & _
                "Time: </strong>" & Now() & _
            "</p>"
        SendMail email_from,email_to,system_name &" 500-100 Error  " & LOGON_USER,"<HTML>" & PATH & "<BR><BR>" & replace(strError,"%2F","/") & "</HTML>" ,2
    %>

    <body>
        <div class="errortitle">Your system has encountered an error...</div>
        <div class="errorbody">
            <div class="errormessage"><%=strError%></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Now, in IIS, navigate to the **Custom Erros** section and scroll down to the **500** error.  **Edit...** this error and select **URL** as the **Message Type**.  In the **URL** box, beneath, type `/errors/error.asp` (remember that the folder should be on the *root of your web server* [this is usually `<drive>\Inetpub\wwwroot`] - if you choose to put it elsewhere then this won't work until you resolve the path).

Now try running your pages again and see if you get any ASP error messages.  Your page *should* be redirected to the error.asp page if there is an error.

(Let me know if there are any errors with the code above - I had to mod it on the fly and haven't had chance to test it).