# Classic ASP 500 Error GetObject("WinNT://

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-7

Getting a 500 error on this line in classic asp.  Strange thing is that an Identical windows server 2008 server with IIS 7 it works fine (Test server).

```
Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://MYCORP/BoxReplacement_Users")
```

1. Do I need to give more permissions to the IIS website?
2. Do I need to install some WinNT thing?

Comment: Obviously they are not quite identical otherwise you would not be getting that error.  WinNT is the namespace name for the Windows provider for Active Directory Service Interfaces.  Is there anything in the IIS or event logs that give more details than just a 500 error? Without that error message it is just a guess as to what the problem actually is.

Comment: Put an `On Error Resume Next ... On Error Goto 0` clause around it and `Response.Write` the error message you get to your page. Alteratively, [have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421660/website-does-not-work-when-moving-the-files-to-another-server/24426437#24426437) post and use the error trapping to recover the error message.

Comment: Had an issue with another developer copying files and seems that moving the files again solved the problem.